# Does changing the app ID associated with a provisioning profile break existing apps deployed with that same provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile

So at the company I work at we had created an iOS app. We created the Provisioning Certificate with the specific App ID for the app (not a wildcard). Now, we're deploying a second app that should be able to receive push notifications from the same server. In the interest of simplicity, it'd be greatly appreciated if both these apps used the same Provisioning Profile so as to not complicate the server with working out which one it should be using.

The dilemma, however, is this: I don't know if changing the App ID (from specific App to a wildcard) on an existing Provisioning Profile that is in use by an already deployed app will break push notifications and other such services for the already deployed app using that provisioning profile. I would try it out, but for obvious reasons don't want to go taking leaps of faith with things Production relies on to function.

Hopefully I explained that ok.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: To clarify, the existing app's ID will be satisified by the Wildcard I want to change the provisioning profile to.

Comment: The notification you receive is according to pem file you used in server and the certificate you used for the app. . . .so two provisioning profile can used same certificate and the same pem file can be generated for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use a wildcard app id with push notifications.

The only way I can foresee this working with a single provisioning profile is for you to build both apps with the same bundle ID, which matches the app ID in the provisioning profile.  The downside of this is that the two apps would not be able to both be installed on the same device at the same time.

If you need that functionality, you'll want to set up a new app ID with push notifications and work out the server side stuff to send push notifications to both app IDs.

Comment: This seems to be  the way you'd have to pull off my original question. Ultimately, in my case, I just bit the bullet and set up multiple provisioning profiles and certificates - with the server determining which app would be appropriate to send to at that time.